# Flutter condition with switch

Tags: flutter, if-statement, switch-statement, logic

hi i am a newbie in coding ,now trying to fetch this api,based on the type of article in to seperate list,

```
[{type: article, data: {post_id: 11530, thumbnail_image: https://www.beingtheparent.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Home-Remedies-For-Swollen-Feet-During-Pregnancy.jpg, count: 15, Title: Home Remedies For Swollen Feet During Pregnancy, content: The word edema denotes swelling and during pregnancy, most women at any stage can suffer from swelling in ankles, hands,.., permalink: https://www.beingtheparent.com/top-10-home-remedies-for-swollen-feet-during-pregnancy/, slug: top-10-home-remedies-for-swollen-feet-during-pregnancy, categoryName: 2b. Health &amp; Safety, categorySlug: health-and-safety, week_category_name: Pregnancy Week 30, week_category_slug: pregnancy-week-30, special_category_name: , special_category_slug: , child_safety_category_name: , child_safety_category_slug: , life_skills_category_name: , life_skills_category_slug: , post_tag_name: Week 29, post_tag_slug: week-29}},

 {type: article, data: {post_id: 11531, thumbnail_image: https://www.beingtheparent.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Home
```

code

```
enum HomeFeedProviderState { idle, loading, loaded, error }

class HomeFeedProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<FeedDataModel2> feedDatacollection = [];

  List<Data22> userpostCollection = [];
  List<Data22> articlesPostcollection = [];
  List<Data22> momsLikeyoucollection = [];

  HomeFeedProviderState currenstState = HomeFeedProviderState.idle;

  static HomeFeedProvider instance = HomeFeedProvider();
  Future<void> fetchHomeFeedData() async {
    currenstState = HomeFeedProviderState.loading;
    notifyListeners();
    var url = 'https://auth.dev.beingtheparent.com/Btpmobileapi/get_feed';

    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var feed = jsonDecode(response.body);

      var data = feed['data'];

      print("feedData$data");

      print("newones ${data['type'].runtimeType}");

      switch (data["type"]) {
        case "article":
          {
            print('kind');
            articlesPostcollection.clear();
            articlesPostcollection.add(data['article']);
            print("hold${articlesPostcollection.length}");
            print('nobody');
            break;
          }
        default:
          {
            print('Unhandleddata type: ${data["type"]}');
            break;
          }
      }

      print("articles$articlesPostcollection");

      FeedDataModel2 feedDataModel2 = FeedDataModel2.fromJson(feed);

      feedDatacollection.clear();

      feedDatacollection.add(feedDataModel2);

      currenstState = HomeFeedProviderState.loaded;

      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      currenstState = HomeFeedProviderState.error;

      print("iconlistdatas${response.statusCode}");
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

can somebody help me with switch condition, in console before switch statement its printing but inside switch statement nothing is executed, also for default case also, Model i had already created

Comment: No action after adding data to `articlesPostcollection`. What kind of work do you want??

Comment: after this i am trying to show this data inside articlepostcollection with the help of provider, but when i print (articlesPostcollection); its not showing anything,also i tried to print("helo"); inside switch statement, its not showing in console

Answer (score 0):

You can use a model to fetch the response data from the API request.

Create a model class like this, (name it whatever you like e.g ArticleModel.dart)

```
    // To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final articleModel = articleModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<ArticleModel> articleModelFromJson(String str) => List<ArticleModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => ArticleModel.fromJson(x)));

String articleModelToJson(List<ArticleModel> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class ArticleModel {
    ArticleModel({
        this.type,
        this.data,
    });

    String? type;
    Data? data;

    factory ArticleModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ArticleModel(
        type: json["type"],
        data: json["data"] == null ? null : Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
    );
}

class Data {
    Data({
        this.postId,
        this.thumbnailImage,
        this.count,
        this.title,
        this.content,
        this.permalink,
        this.slug,
        this.categoryName,
        this.categorySlug,
        this.weekCategoryName,
        this.weekCategorySlug,
        this.specialCategoryName,
        this.specialCategorySlug,
        this.childSafetyCategoryName,
        this.childSafetyCategorySlug,
        this.lifeSkillsCategoryName,
        this.lifeSkillsCategorySlug,
        this.postTagName,
        this.postTagSlug,
    });

    int? postId;
    String? thumbnailImage;
    int? count;
    String? title;
    String? content;
    String? permalink;
    String? slug;
    String? categoryName;
    String? categorySlug;
    String? weekCategoryName;
    String? weekCategorySlug;
    String? specialCategoryName;
    String? specialCategorySlug;
    String? childSafetyCategoryName;
    String? childSafetyCategorySlug;
    String? lifeSkillsCategoryName;
    String? lifeSkillsCategorySlug;
    String? postTagName;
    String? postTagSlug;

    factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        postId: json["post_id"],
        thumbnailImage: json["thumbnail_image"],
        count: json["count"],
        title: json["Title"],
        content: json["content"],
        permalink: json["permalink"],
        slug: json["slug"],
        categoryName: json["categoryName"],
        categorySlug: json["categorySlug"],
        weekCategoryName: json["week_category_name"],
        weekCategorySlug: json["week_category_slug"],
        specialCategoryName: json["special_category_name"],
        specialCategorySlug: json["special_category_slug"],
        childSafetyCategoryName: json["child_safety_category_name"],
        childSafetyCategorySlug: json["child_safety_category_slug"],
        lifeSkillsCategoryName: json["life_skills_category_name"],
        lifeSkillsCategorySlug: json["life_skills_category_slug"],
        postTagName: json["post_tag_name"],
        postTagSlug: json["post_tag_slug"],
    );
}
```

Now create a variable in which all this response is going to be stored.

```
var articleModel = ArticleModel();
```

Now fetch the response using this model as follows,

```
final result = jsonDecode(data); // if you're using a RestAPI
articleModel = ArticleModel.fromJson(result);
```

Now use the articleModel.(name of the key here) to fetch whatever your want or like to do with the data.

For example, in your case you want to access the type article.
You'll access it by

```
print(articleModel[0].type); // prints the type of value at first first 
index which is "Article".
```

Comment: thanks for replying i already done decoding of data,by JsonDecode,but the issue with now is inside switch statement  nothing is executed ,i will update the code